# Campos como checked ou não, trazem sempre o mesmo valor

Tags: php, javascript, html

Caros, bom dia. 
Estou com um determinado problema, onde deve ser feito a escolha de 3 campos de verificação, caso os 3 campos estejam unchecked, retorne a mensagem de campo vazio, caso contrario, traga os valores dos determinados campos.

O que acontece é que, eles estando como checked ou não, eles trazem sempre a mesma ocorrencia, no caso o valor do primeiro campo.

Html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 m-b-15">
<h5>Primeira checagem</h5>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="checagem1" value="prioridade" name="checagem1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="materialChecked2">Prioridade</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="checagem1" value="tentativas" name="checagem1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="materialChecked2">Tentativas</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="checagem1" value="agendamento" name="checagem1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="materialChecked2">Agendamento</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 m-b-15">
<h5>Segunda checagem</h5>              
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="checagem2" value="prioridade" name="checagem2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="materialChecked2">Prioridade</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="checagem2" value="tentativas" name="checagem2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="materialChecked2">Tentativas</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="checagem2" value="agendamento" name="checagem2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="materialChecked2">Agendamento</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 m-b-15">
 <h5>Terceira checagem</h5>              
      <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="checagem3" value="prioridade" name="checagem3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="materialChecked2">Prioridade</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="checagem3" value="tentativas" name="checagem3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="materialChecked2">Tentativas</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="checagem3" value="agendamento" name="checagem3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="materialChecked2">Agendamento</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    var $status = document.getElementById("status").checked;
            var $intstatus = 1;
            if ($status ==true) {$intstatus=0;}
            var $qtdtentativas = document.getElementById("qtdtentativas").value;
            var $intervalo = document.getElementById("intervalo").value;
            var $destino = document.getElementById("destino").value;
            var $skill = document.getElementById("skill").value;
            var $pacing = document.getElementById("pacing").value;
            var $prefixo = document.getElementById("prefixo").value;
          //  var $prioridade = document.getElementById("prioridade").value;
            var $checagem1 = document.getElementById("checagem1").value;
            var $checagem2 = document.getElementById("checagem2").value;
            var $checagem3 = document.getElementById("checagem3").value;
            var $horainicio = document.getElementById("horainicio").value;
            var $horafinal = document.getElementById("horafinal").value;

            //+"&prioridade="+ $prioridade 

            var strurl = "gravadb.php?status="+$intstatus + "&intervalo=" +$intervalo + "&destino=" + $destino + "&qtdtentativas=" + $qtdtentativas + "&skill=" + $skill + "&pacing=" + $pacing + "&prefixo=" + $prefixo + "&horainicio=" + $horainicio + "&horafinal=" + $horafinal +"&prioridade1="+ $checagem1 +"&prioridade2="+ $checagem2 +"&prioridade3="+ $checagem3 + "";
            window.location.href = strurl;
```

PHP

```
    $prioridade1 = $_GET['prioridade1'];
    $prioridade2 = $_GET['prioridade2'];
    $prioridade3 = $_GET['prioridade3'];

    if(empty($prioridade1) || empty($prioridade2) || empty($prioridade3)){
        echo 'Preencha o campo de checagem';
    }else{
        echo "prioridade 1 = ".$prioridade1." prioridade 2 = ".$prioridade2." prioridade 3 = ".$prioridade3;
    }
```

Retorno:

```
prioridade 1 = prioridade prioridade 2 = prioridade prioridade 3 = prioridade
```

edit 1:

Alterando o id para ser unico para cada elemento. Entretanto a requisição que estou realizando agora é via o name através de getElementsByName(); 
Ainda assim ele não retorna valor nenhum.

```
 var $checagem1 = document.getElementsByName("checagem1").value;
 var $checagem2 = document.getElementsByName("checagem2").value;
 var $checagem3 = document.getElementsByName("checagem3").value;
```

Comment: São três ids para cada checagem?

Comment: sim, a ideia é, ter 3 checagens e cada uma destas podem ter 3 opções. Eu não sei se declarando o mesmo ID para as 3 como fiz esta correto...

Comment: se eu alterar o ID, ele até pega outros valores, mas eu necessito que, seja pego apenas o que esta checado

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver este problema que apresentei, tive que recorrer ao javascript da seguinte forma:

```
var choices = [];
                   var els = document.getElementsByName('checagem1');
                   for (var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
                     if ( els[i].checked ) {
                       choices.push(els[i].value);
                     }
                   }
                   var choices1 = [];
                    var els1 = document.getElementsByName('checagem2');
                   for (var i=0;i<els1.length;i++){
                     if ( els1[i].checked ) {
                       choices1.push(els1[i].value);
                     }
                   }
                   var choices2 = [];
                    var els2 = document.getElementsByName('checagem3');
                   for (var i=0;i<els2.length;i++){
                     if ( els2[i].checked ) {
                       choices2.push(els2[i].value);
                     }
                   }

                   var $checagem1 = choices;
                   var $checagem2 = choices1;
                   var $checagem3 = choices2;
```

sendo assim eu consigo pegar apenas o elemento que esta checado, não sendo necessario realizar a separação pelo ID mas sim, pelo name.